# How to access checkboxes in a List view one by one

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to check all text boxes on the basis of if the check box is checked. But I don't know how to access all check boxes one by one? I bound it with ApprovalStatus which is of boolean type. Can any one help me to have code in C#?

```
<CheckBox Content="Check All" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,193,0,0" Name="Tab2CheckAll" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" Click="Tab2CheckAll_Click"/>

<ListView Height="213" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,215,0,0" Name="Tab2EmployeeEffortList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="771" AllowDrop="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Approved" Width="100">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding ApprovalStatus}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to access individual checkBoxes. CheckBox is already bounded to property set that instead.

Loop over `ItemsSource` of `ListView` and set `ApprovalStatus` to `true` for all items in the collection. As long as your underlying source class is implementing [**INotifyPropertyChanged**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it will work fine.